# Revert Gradle build in Eclipse :

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle

I was trying to install Android Studio and import a project from eclipse. So i export following the documentation steps : i build gradle file. 
Now on my Eclipse IDE, I have an error on the 4th line below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:pj="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.myApp"
```

The error is :

```
In Gradle projects, always use 
http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto for custom attributes
```

What should I do? I changed it as they say but I fear I might lost compatibility.

Can I 'destroy' the gradle build? recompile?

Answer (score 0):

First you should have checked that gradle build works in Eclipse.

What you need to do is check/compare .project and .classpath files (hidden by default) with any other Android project